# CSS Media Screen

Tags: css, media-queries

I am using CSS code to scale down the text when my website is displayed on a mobile device or tablet. The problem is, it is scaling down the text on Google Chrome on my laptop as well, even though my laptop is not a mobile device. Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
@media screen (moz-max-device-pixel-ratio: 3.0),
    (-o-max-device-pixel-ratio: 3.0),
    (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 3.0),
    (max-device-pixel-ratio: 3.0), {
    .album {
        font-size: 5px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 3),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 288dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 3dppx) { 

  /* Retina-specific stuff here */
    .album {
      font-size:5px;
    }

}
```

```
**Min device pixel ratio**      =        **min resolution**

2                                        192dpi
1.25                                     120dpi
1.3                                      124.8dpi
1.5                                      144dpi


1dppx is equivalent to 96dpi
```

[reference](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)

Comment: may I ask how comes you are using "min" and not "max". The idea is I want any device above ratio 3 to not be affected.

Comment: ok that seems to have worked thank you, may I ask what the signicant of the "dpi" and "ddx" is?

Comment: thank you for your explanation on dppx, that has helped very much. I am still confused as to why it works on min-device and not max-device.

Comment: general laptops have 1 pixel ratio, retina display has 2. Personally I never faced 3 pixel ratio.